# Laravel Homestead not printing out to console with var_dump() or dump() during unit tests

Tags: laravel, phpunit, homestead

I have a homestead instance of a project and am running my unit tests using the `php artisan test` command. However I'm unable to print anything to console within any tests that are run.

```
public function testTest()
    {
        var_dump('testing print to console');
        dump('testing print to console');
        echo('testing print to console');
    }
```

When running `php artisan test` this test actually runs but none of the strings can printed out to the console

Comment: Try ```dd();```

Comment: aah that worked. I guess var_dump works if theres a die in there also

Answer (score 1):

So for some reason var_dump will only work with a `dd()` or `die()` after it